# Disable scrolling in Konzept Slideshow

Tags: jquery, scroll, slider, slideshow

I recently installed Daisho theme. It comes with different scrolling techniques. Such as with trackpad. Whenever I try to scroll down the page, the trackpad scrolling scrolls Slideshow so fast and messy. Is there a way to disable this scrolling?

My website: http://www.waavinetwork.com

Answer (score 1):

Find these lines in your code and remove them

```
$("#konzept_slideshow").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
var dir = delta > 0 ? slideshow_prev_slide() : slideshow_next_slide();
    event.preventDefault();
})
```